# Is there a way to programmatically download zipped files from the G.Drive?

Tags: javascript, download, google-drive-api, drive

I got a library of several books and want the user to be able to download any of them with the select tag in my html page using some js. So far whatever I did (on the server side and client side) it throw me to a different url. getting lost as I'm new to that. Any help much appreciated.
I just put below the latest try I did

That's the html & js script

```
<html>
.....
    <div class="input-field col s4 form-text">
        <button id="download" class="waves-effect blue-grey darken-1 btn" > <i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>Download </button> 
   </div>  

<!-- I got an eventListener-->
 <script>
   document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click",downloadMyBook);
 </script>
....
</html>
```

on the script (client side)  side

```
<script>

  function downloadMyBook() {
     var sel = document.getElementById("selected_book");
     var title= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
     google.script.run.GetThatBook(title); // send a job to the server
    }
</script>
```

on the server side

```
function doGet(e){

}

function GetThatBook(text){
   // reading  the files description from a G.Sheet
   var url = "";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("2019");
   var records = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-2,12);
   // All detailed for clarity-Debugging purpose 
   var myBooks = records.map(function(r){return r[0]}); // Book titles
   var myLinks = records.map(function(r){return r[8]}); // the google IDs
   var index = myBooks.indexOf(text); // identify the index in the array of the one of interest
   var fileID = myLinks[index] ; // get it's ID as it's recorded in the G.sheet

   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID); // here is the blocking point

   if(file){
        return true;
   }
  else{
        return false;
       }
```

}

I wish I could get the file (they're all zipped) being dowloaded but looks like the process is more complicated than what I expecting.
(Question edited as required. I apologise - did it wrong

Comment: You have an extra quote here: `getRange('A1'")`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: @barmar oups (probably unproper keyboard use from me).  var records =  ws_Ressources_Produites.getRange(3,2,ws_Ressources_Produites.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-2,11).getValues();

Comment: Don't put it in a comment, edit the question so it matches your actual code. Best is to just copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

For your own comment on your question, I assumed you forgot to put the getValues() function at the end of the line where you get the records variable.

Changes needed in your code:

1) To serve an HTML in your App Script Web App, you need to return an HtmlOutput object in your doGet() function [1]. Also, here are the instructions to deploy a Web App in App Script, in case you don’t know [2].

2) As you said, after the GetThatBook function runs it redirects you to a different Url, this is because you’re not handling the response of that function. You need to use the withSuccessHandler function to handle the response if it’s successful [3]. I also use the withFailureHandler function to print the error and debug the code.

3) To obtain the Url to download the file you get, you need to use the getDownloadUrl() function to the File object [4].

4) Currently there’s a bug from google about the Url you get with this method, you can see it here [5]. The workaround they suggest is to delete the last parameter of the Url, this can be done using substring function.

5) Finally, in the success handler function (updateUrl) you can redirect the app to the Url that will download the file.

Here is your code tweaked by me, which I tested and worked successfully downloading the file:

**Index.html (Client side):**

```
<script>
      document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click",downloadMyBook);

      function downloadMyBook() {
         var sel = document.getElementById("selected_book");
         var title= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
         google.script.run.withFailureHandler(error).withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).GetThatBook(title); // send a job to the server
      }

    //
      function updateUrl(url) {
       window.location.href = url;
      }

      function error(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }

  </script>
```

**Code.gs (Server side):**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function GetThatBook(text){
   // reading  the files description from a G.Sheet
   var url = "";
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("2019");
   var records = ws.getRange(1,1,ws.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow()-2,12).getValues();
   // All detailed for clarity-Debugging purpose 
   var myBooks = records.map(function(r){return r[0]}); // Book titles
   var myLinks = records.map(function(r){return r[8]}); // the google IDs
   var index = myBooks.indexOf(text); // identify the index in the array of the one of interest
   var fileID = myLinks[index] ; // get it's ID as it's recorded in the G.sheet

  // From this part, I would suggest to use another way to do this part (using try/catch) because it will throw an error if it doesn’t find the file with that fileID. 

   var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID); // here is the blocking point
   //Get Url
   var url = file.getDownloadUrl();


   If (file) {
   //Fix Url and return it to client side
        return url.substring(0, url.length -8);
   } else {
        return "No file";
   }
}
```

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl

[5] https://b.corp.google.com/issues/36761174#comment3

Comment: Thanks a lot Andres. i'll dig into it carefully.